# Change checkbox checked on dropdown's SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, selectedindexchanged

Why does the checkbox doesn't get set to checked when I change the selected item in dropdown?

aspx

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOption" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="selectValue" Width="100px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOption_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOpt1" runat="server" Text="Option 1" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOpt2" runat="server" Text="Option 2" />
```

cs

```
protected void ddlOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ddlOption.SelectedValue == "1")
      {
         chkOpt1.Checked = true;
         chkOpt2.Checked = false;
      }
   else
      {
         chkOpt1.Checked = false;
         chkOpt2.Checked = true;
      }
}
```

When I debug the program, the Checked attribute is set correctly but this doesn't change in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `AutoPostBack` property;

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOpt1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Option 1" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOpt2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Option 2" />
```